# Difference between escape(), encodeURI(), encodeURIComponent()

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, what is the difference between these?

1. `escape()` / `unescape()`
2. `encodeuri()` / `decodeuri()`
3. `encodeURIComponent()` / `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Do the related questions help?

Comment: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Comment: One major difference is that `encodeURI` won't encode `/` so: `encodeURIComponent("ac/dc")` => `ac%2Fdc` and `encodeURI("ac/dc")` => `ac/dc`

Answer (score 73):

For the visually minded, here's a table showing the effects of `encodeURI()`, `encodeURIComponent()` and `escape()` on the commonly-used symbolic ASCII characters:

```
Char  encUrI  encURIComp  escape
*     *       *           *
.     .       .           .
_     _       _           _
-     -       -           -
~     ~       ~           %7E
'     '       '           %27
!     !       !           %21
(     (       (           %28
)     )       )           %29
/     /       %2F         /
+     +       %2B         +
@     @       %40         @
?     ?       %3F         %3F
=     =       %3D         %3D
:     :       %3A         %3A
#     #       %23         %23
;     ;       %3B         %3B
,     ,       %2C         %2C
$     $       %24         %24
&     &       %26         %26
      %20     %20         %20
%     %25     %25         %25
^     %5E     %5E         %5E
[     %5B     %5B         %5B
]     %5D     %5D         %5D
{     %7B     %7B         %7B
}     %7D     %7D         %7D
<     %3C     %3C         %3C
>     %3E     %3E         %3E
"     %22     %22         %22
\     %5C     %5C         %5C
|     %7C     %7C         %7C
`     %60     %60         %60
```

Another vital difference is that `unescape()` does not handle multi-byte UTF-8 sequences whereas `decodeURI[Component]()` does:

```
decodeURIComponent("%C3%A9") == "é"
unescape("%C3%A9") == "Ã©"
```

Answer (score 46):

- `escape` — broken, deprecated, do not use
- `encodeURI` — encodes characters that are not allowed (raw) in URLs (use it to fix up broken URIs if you can't fix them beforehand)
- `encodeURIComponent` — as `encodeURI` plus characters with special meaning in URIs (use it to encode data for inserting into a URI)

Comment: Examples of how you would use them would be super helpful. For instance, `encodeURI('http://something.com?whatever')` and `'http://example.com?something=' + encodeURIComponent(userInputVariable)` etc

Answer (score 26):

First of all - Escape is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

**encodeURI()**

You should use this when you want to encode a URL, it encodes symbols that is not allowed in a URL.

**encodeURIComponent()**

Should be used when you want to encode parameters of your URL, You can also use this to encode a whole URL. But you would have to decode it in order to use it again.

--

I'd say this a duplicate. Here's a good answer on SO - Credits goes to Arne Evertsson:
[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

There's a lot of details on why/why not on that topic.

Answer (score 9):

- `escape` - deprecated, you shouldn't use.
- `encodeURI` - replaces all characters except
  `; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) # a-z 0-9`
- `encodeURIComponent` - replaces all characters except
  `- _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) a-z 0-9`

Answer (score 1):

Just try `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` yourself...

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('@#$%^&*'));
```

Input: `@#$%^&*`.  Output: `%40%23%24%25%5E%26*`.  So, wait, what happened to `*`?  Why wasn't this converted?  TLDR: You actually want [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).  Long-story...

- `escape()` : ***Do Not Use!!!*** To quote [**MDN `escape()` Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)...

> Warning: Although escape() is not strictly deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is defined in Annex B of the ECMA-262 standard, whose introduction states:

> ... Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours when writing new ECMAScript code....

- `encodeURI()` : ***Do Not Use!!!*** Use `fixedEncodeURI()`. To quote [**MDN `encodeURI()` Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)...

> If one wishes to follow the more recent RFC3986 for URLs, which makes square brackets reserved (for IPv6) and thus not encoded when forming something which could be part of a URL (such as a host), the following code snippet may help:

> `function fixedEncodeURI(str) { return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']'); }`

- `encodeURIComponent()` : ***Do Not Use!!!*** Use `fixedEncodeURIComponent()`. To quote the [**MDN encodeURIComponent() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)...

> To be more stringent in adhering to RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:

> `function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) { return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) { return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); }); }`

Then the question can be simplified: What's the difference between `fixedEncodeURI()` and `fixedEncodeURIComponent()`?  `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` encodes the following characters, while `fixedEncodeURI()` does not: `+@?=:#;,$&`.