# JSON.stringify and encodeuricomponent

Tags: javascript

My string for my AJAX GET request looks like the following:

```
return domain + '?x=' + JSON.stringify(x)
```

Do need to use `encodeUriComponent` to make the URI valid? For example:

```
return domain + '?x=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(x))
```

Comment: @mplungjan: most likely the person voted to close because it would depend on the input given. The question could have used some clarification, but without a comment the questioner would have no idea what should have been done. Unless the question's really poor, people shouldn't be just doing hit-and-run voting.

Comment: Anyway, this is presuming that you haven't escaped it yourself yet, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` doesn't escape characters, it just returns you string representation and as you are using it in url you need to escape it using `encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 9):

This is what I understand from reading some posts and answers (please feel free to correct me)

JSON - **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation

- Use **JSON.stringify** when you have a JavaScript Object and you want to convert it to a string (containing a JSON text). This is called serialization.
- Use **JSON.parse** when you wish to convert a string (which contains a JSON text) to a JavaScript object (e.g. if you get a string containing a JSON text from the session storage and you want to convert it to JSON and use some of the fields of the object). This is called deserialization, and it is the opposite of JSON.stringify.

Regardless to JSON:

- Use **encodeURIComponent** whenever you want to send "problematic" characters in the URL such as &, % etc. The opposite is decodeURIComponent.

I used these answers for my summary:

[Difference between JSON.stringify and JSON.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse)

[difference between escape, encodeuri, encodeURIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317861/difference-between-escape-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. The JSON is expressed as a *text* and you are adding it as a component of a URI, so you should.

Answer (score 0):

can use rc4 encode(or base64 if content not too length) in url then decode in process file